# Classes not found in third party iOS framework

Tags: appcelerator-hyperloop

I am using `Appcelerator Hyperloop` in the hopes of integrating a third party iOS framework called `KolorEyes` into my `Titanium` app.

Here is my `appc.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
hyperloop: {
    ios: {
        xcodebuild: {
            flags: {
                FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS: '../../src',
                LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS: '@executable_path'
            },
            frameworks: [
                'KolorEyes'
            ]
        },
        thirdparty: {
            'KolorEyes': {
                source: ['src'],
                header: 'src',
                resource: 'src'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

};

I have my `KolorEyes.framework` folder in my `src` folder at the root of my project.

What I'm doing looks like it should work:

`index.js`

```
var KolorEyes = require('KolorEyes/KolorEyes');
var KolorEyesSessionParams = require('KolorEyes/KolorEyesSessionParams');
var KolorEyesRenderViewParams = require('KolorEyes/KolorEyesRenderViewParams');

console.log('CLASS: ' + KolorEyes);
console.log('CLASS: ' + KolorEyesSessionParams);
console.log('CLASS: ' + KolorEyesRenderViewParams);
```

And here is the output:

```
[INFO] :   CLASS: [class KolorEyes]
[INFO] :   CLASS: [class KolorEyesSessionParams]
[INFO] :   CLASS: [class KolorEyesRenderViewParams]
```

But when I try to do this:

```
var params = KolorEyesSessionParams.alloc().init();
```

It tells me it cannot find the class `KolorEyesSessionParams`:

```
[ERROR] :  Cannot find class with name: KolorEyesSessionParams
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      column = 32;
[ERROR] :      description = "Cannot find class with name: KolorEyesSessionParams";
[ERROR] :      line = 108;
[ERROR] :      message = "Cannot find class with name: KolorEyesSessionParams";
[ERROR] :      name = ClassNotFound;
[ERROR] :      nativeStack = "1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x23a6ae17 objc_exception_throw + 38\n2   kolor_test                          0x0019ce0b kolor_test + 1515019\n3   kolor_test                          0x00195d05 kolor_test + 1486085\n4   JavaScriptCore                      0x275f77cd <redacted> + 364\n5   JavaScriptCore                      0x273c7dfb <redacted> + 314\n6   JavaScriptCore                      0x273c6629 <redacted> + 120\n7   JavaScriptCore                      0x2768302f <redacted> + 20366\n8   JavaScriptCore                      0x27683039 <redacted> + 20376\n9   JavaScriptCore                      0x2767de91 <redacted> + 336\n10  JavaScriptCore                      0x275d87db <redacted> + 102\n11  JavaScriptCore                      0x273caa09 <redacted> + 344\n12  JavaScriptCore                      0x273ca8ad _ZN3JSC4callEPNS_9ExecStateENS_7JSValueENS_8CallTypeERKNS_8CallDataES2_RKNS_7ArgListE + 52\n13  JavaScriptCore                      0x275887a3 <redacted> + 126\n14  JavaScriptCore                      0x276dc183 _ZNK3JSC12PropertySlot14functionGetterEPNS_9ExecStateE + 42\n15  JavaScriptCore                      0x273c220b <redacted> + 1406\n16  JavaScriptCore                      0x276804ed <redacted> + 9292\n17  JavaScriptCore                      0x27683039 <redacted> + 20376\n18  JavaScriptCore                      0x27683135 <redacted> + 20628\n19  JavaScriptCore                      0x27683039 <redacted> + 20376\n20  JavaScriptCore                      0x2767de91 <redacted> + 336\n21  JavaScriptCore                      0x275d87db <redacted> + 102\n22  JavaScriptCore                      0x273b8d0d <redacted> + 7292\n23  JavaScriptCore                      0x274c839b _ZN3JSC8evaluateEPNS_9ExecStateERKNS_10SourceCodeENS_7JSValueERN3WTF8NakedPtrINS_9ExceptionEEE + 354\n24  JavaScriptCore                      0x275f6ba5 JSEvaluateScript + 268\n25  kolor_test                          0x0003c91d kolor_test + 71965\n26  kolor_test                          0x00042fa7 kolor_test + 98215\n27  kolor_test                          0x00044741 kolor_test + 104257\n28  kolor_test                          0x00044b81 kolor_test + 105345\n29  kolor_test                          0x0003caf3 kolor_test + 72435\n30  kolor_test                          0x0003da83 kolor_test + 76419\n31  kolor_test                          0x00045589 kolor_test + 107913\n32  kolor_test                          0x00044521 kolor_test + 103713\n33  libdispatch.dylib                   0x23e3d823 <redacted> + 10\n34  libdispatch.dylib                   0x23e3d80f <redacted> + 22\n35  libdispatch.dylib                   0x23e4bba9 <redacted> + 1524\n36  CoreFoundation                      0x24291b6d <redacted> + 8\n37  CoreFoundation                      0x24290067 <redacted> + 1574\n38  CoreFoundation                      0x241df229 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520\n39  CoreFoundation                      0x241df015 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108\n40  GraphicsServices                    0x257cfac9 GSEventRunModal + 160\n41  UIKit                               0x288b3189 UIApplicationMain + 144\n42  kolor_test                          0x00030747 kolor_test + 22343\n43  libdyld.dylib                       0x23e87873 <redacted> + 2";
[ERROR] :      sourceURL = "file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/1536D545-76AB-48FA-BDF7-C2729A175F82/kolor_test.app/hyperloop/koloreyes/koloreyessessionparams.js";
[ERROR] :  }
```

I have no issue using `UIKit` stuff, but these third party classes are just not seen. Even though `Hyperloop` says it's generating classes for them:

```
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class GLKit/GLKView
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class GLKit/GLKViewController
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class KolorEyes/KolorEyes
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class KolorEyes/KolorEyesRenderViewParams
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class KolorEyes/KolorEyesSessionParams
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class ModelIO/MDLCamera
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Generating class ModelIO/MDLLight
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: @StevenH We ended up using GoogleVR :) No resolution for the specific issue above though.

Comment: @StevenH - i added an answer/explanation

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same issue. According to this response, the issue is that a framework is being used on a platform earlier than what the framework was created for.

Can confirm that once I rebuilt the framework (needed to build against iOS 12 instead of iOS 13) with an older version of the SDK that this issue was resolved for me.

> This is a general issue where you cannot run version-specific code on
> older devices. Will move and rename it, thanks for reporting this!
>
> Jan Vennemann That's what we discussed a few days ago. I have no final
> plan for this, yet, but as the error occurs with referencing the iOS
> framework (not the actual API) that's only available in a certain
> version and higher (in this case: "Speech.framework", iOS 10+), we may
> be able to solve this by guarding the frameworks with their iOS
> version if their version is higher then the default one (e.g. 8.1 in
> our case).
>
> I could even think of a workaround: If we pass link the framework via
> the appc.js, we can pass linker-flags as well, so something like I've
> done in my ARKit module maybe. Btw, this could eventually be a
> module-related issue as well, as we don't need the module.xcconfig
> there anymore and frameworks are linked automatically. If we can
> ensure to pass them to the correct architecture and version, we should
> be fine!

Source:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25440?focusedCommentId=429553&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-429553